# Selenium Java Запуск многопоточных тестов помогите плиз

Tags: java, selenium

Всем привет) Хочу запустить несколько тестовых классов одновременно. Столкнулся с проблемой, что мой базовый класс не запускается, java просит main method, но в уроках которые я смотрю никакого main нет. Как запустить тесты без метода main?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class MyTest extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.click();
        q.sendKeys("Hello world!\n");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.click();
        q.sendKeys("Hello world!\n");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.click();
        q.sendKeys("Hello world!\n");
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class MyTest2 extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.click();
        q.sendKeys("Hello world!\n");
    }
    @Test
    public void test2(){
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.click();
        q.sendKeys("Hello world!\n");
    }
    @Test
    public void test3(){
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.click();
        q.sendKeys("Hello world!\n");
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestBase {

    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> tldriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    @Before
    public void start(){
        if (tldriver.get() != null){
            driver = tldriver.get();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            return;
        }
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        tldriver.set(driver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }));
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.software-testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Ну по первой же ссылке в гугле https://www.baeldung.com/maven-junit-parallel-tests видно, что надо добавить <parrallel>true в конфигурацию

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class TestBase, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
Вот что меня интересует